# I'm not able to find optimtools in MATLAB and run this project in MATLAB_R2023a

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run the "Stock Market Prediction using Neural Networks and Genetic Algorithm" project on my local machine (Mac) for a college project. The project is available on GitHub: [Project_Link](https://github.com/Shikhar1998/Stock-Market-Prediction-using-Neural-Networks-and-Genetic-Algorithm).

I encountered some issues while setting it up, and I would appreciate any help in getting it to run correctly.
] I'm still facing the following challenges:

The optimtools module, which is used to trigger the main fitfunction ([link](https://github.com/Shikhar1998/Stock-Market-Prediction-using-Neural-Networks-and-Genetic-Algorithm/issues/10)), has been deprecated. Is there an alternative solution or approach I can use to replace this functionality?
I encountered an error related to the toolbox object not being defined.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve these issues and successfully run the project on my Mac.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution by mathworks themselves is to use the live editor optimization.

You can launch a guided example of it with:

```
open GetStartedWithOptimizeLiveEditorTaskExample
```

Your selection should be solver based, use the one from github 'gamultobj'. Note tha this most probably will require the **Global Optimization Toolbox**.

In the optimize section you can find an interactive gui quite similar to the optimtool one where you can try to replicate your project.

You have upper and lower bounds for constraints and all.
To use the abcd fitness function that comes from github use the 'from file' option of the objective function and select it.